# What AWS charges are incurred if I upload images through API Gateway RestAPI to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking to understand what charges exactly are going to be incurred if I was to for example create an API Gateway RestAPI-private ( and perhaps an asp.net core web API ) which stream images/documents into S3 bucket.

The reason why I am considering this is to utilize existing RestAPI authentication mechanism which is in place for private RestAPI, and avoid any complexity around trying to allow s3 uploads using things like direct connect.

I was told by someone that doing something such as this would cause the bill to rise, and there were concerns about costs.

Just looking to understand all the costs involved. Again, all I am looking for here is an API Endpoint which clients can upload images to, and avoiding all the complexity involved with trying to create some private connection between on prem clients and s3 (which looks complex)

Is anyone doing something similar to this?

Comment: Are you expecting files bigger then 10mb for a single upload? If not you don't need to worry about chunking and cost calc should be fairly straight forward. What's your ballpark estimate per day of number of uploads?

Comment: I don’t know what the max size would be, which is exactly why I need to know so that if there is in fact a limit, I document the limit now, state the assumption that the size I plan to include is not in excess of that. I’d like to do that now rather than build something and end up determining later what the capacity is upon a failure in production.

Comment: Upload count is heavy, let’s say some pdf docs may be 100 pages long.

Answer (score 0):

So as per the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html), the max single payload size apigateway can handle is 10mb. Taking the assumption that all request POST's will be under that limit the costs will take into consideration charges from [ApiGateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/), [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) and (assuming you want to handle the files first) [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/). Without knowing your region, pricing is determined by US-East-2 (Ohio), and **free-tier** is taken as **non-existent** (max charges).
Breaking the pricing into those 3 sections, you can expect the following:

> Total - $6.72 USD/month

- ApiGateway ~ $0.88 USD

HTTPS API used for uploading data. The API is called 100k time a month to upload documents which on average is 5 MB in size: `[100,000 * (5mb /512kb)] * [1/1,000,000] = $0.8789`

- S3 ~ $1.65 USD

50 GB of files for a month with standard storage and no GET requests: `[50 * 0.023] + [100,000 x 0.000005] = $1.65`

- Lambda ~ $4.19 USD

512MB of memory for the function, executed 100k times in one month, and it ran for 5 seconds each time: `[(100,000 * 5) * (512/1024) * $0.00001667] + [$0.20 * 0.1] = $4.1875`

If you want more specific information on a service, I suggest you look at the AWS Doc pricing links I included for each service which have a very extensive breakdown of costs.